# Chaining PingFederate Adapters

Tags: pingfederate

I am completely new to PingFederate and SSO .
We are using using PingID for authenticating users to our applications.
I am trying to add another layer of security on top of it. I am trying to interpret the SSO requests and forward it to another application that will generate a ALLOW/DENY access output based on a custom score.
In this new layer , we are trying to avoid any new UI screen (unlike where you provide say a new screen to validate against an OTP).

My question is , is it possible to build to extend a pingId adapter that can provide this new layer of authentication at the background , without the user having to go through a new screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ping currently doesn't have the PingID integration "open source", so you would have to either build your own to include your functionality, or build your own adapter for your risk (or whatever) to use post-PingID adapter.

As an alternative, can you leverage the [REST API Datastore](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-103/page/mby1564002976985.html) to pull the score back for the user and then use issuance criteria?

Comment: Which pingId adapter can I extend , basically I don't want the user to go through any new screen

Comment: You can't. They aren't open source. The user will have to redirect through a new adapter, as I stated, or build using the new PingOne MFA API's.